# how to select radio button by text in UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, safari, radio-button, uiwebview

I have a webpage that has a radio button(with text beside it).
The radio button can be select by the text in PC/Mac browser(IE, Chrome, Safari).
But it can't be select by text in the iPad's safari.  It only can be select by the radio dot.

I want to embed it in iOS UIWebView which I think it's core is safari.

How to solve it that the it can be select by the radio's text in iPad?

Answer (score 0):

yes it doesnt support "for" attribute. maybe you can handle with js

```
<label for="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('radio').setAttribute('checked', '');">TestTest</label>
```

OR Global jQuery

```
$('label[for]').click(function(){
  $('#'+$(this).attr('for')).attr('checked','checked');
});
```